# xfce4 + i3 are not properly restoring saved sessions?

Tags: xfce, i3, session, restore

I'm using manjaro with xfce4 and i3 as my wm. So far so good, the problem that I'm usually facing is that whenever I logout from my current session and log back in all my apps are closed and the session is not properly restored. It's like every time that I logout and login back again I end with a new session instead of restoring the old session which is my intention.

Here's my current `xfce4-session` settings

[image]

Here's my `i3` config line that is used to logout

```
bindsym $mod+shift+x exec xfce4-session-logout
```

And here's a step by step example of what I mean not properly restoring the saved session.

Currently, I have open my browser and pdf reader on a specific pdf.

[image]

After logging out and then back in, here's what I get.
My pdf reader has successfully opened but without properly opening the pdf I was reading when I logged out.

Furthermore, my browser has completely failed to open restoring its status before the logging out event.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a better result, try using i3-specific tools to save and restore your layout, like [i3-resurrect](https://pypi.org/project/i3-resurrect/).

The fact that your PDF view doesn't restore it's own state when it's re-opened is an application-specific issue. You can research PDF viewers which support re-opened the previously opened documents if that's important to yo.

Comment: Thanks, Mark, I'll have a look at your suggestions and report back if I find anything interesting.